# Why substringof, startswith and endswith BreezeJs predicates are not working with EntityFramework + MySql?

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, breeze

I'm using BreezeJs + EntityFramework6 + MySql and predicates: "substringof", "startswith" and "endswith" are not working. I always get 0 results.

"equal"(eq) predicate is working as expected.

So, is it possible to use these predicates for filtering? If so, how?

Comment: Please try to always include specific details in your title so that others may find it easily. If possible, add a short example that would allow others to reproduce this.

Comment: Did you ever solve this - i have exactly the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Shog9 about elaborating your question.

The "startswith" clause clearly works for the Breeze/WebApi/EF/**MS SQLServer** statck. It appears that the fly in the ointment is your usage of MySql.

I suggest that you test your server setup to confirm that you can EF LINQ query your MySql database with `StartsWith` ... completely independently of Breeze. I suspect that you'll find the root of your problem there, perhaps in establishing the proper EF adapter for MySql. **This has nothing to do with Breeze**.

If you can't get that going, you may have better luck asking for help from EF experts.

Once you've got that straightened out ... come back and tell us if that solved your troubles with using Breeze.

Thanks for exploring this pathway. And happy coding!

Comment: Hello @Ward! Thanks for answering. Check EF LINQ queries with my Mysql was one of the first things that I checked and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a case sensitivity issue.  Try having your startsWith, endsWith strings match either the beginning or the end of the string exactly, i.e. cased the same way as what is in the database. Case sensitivity is database specific. See discussion of the *localQueryComparisonOptions* in the API to see how to have breeze local queries match your database options.

Comment: Thanks @Jay Traband. I checked this too and doesn't work. Every OData clauses works very well except for those 3. And the matter that really broke my head is the fact that EF LINQ Methods Contains, StartsWith and EndsWith alone, without Breeze, works as expected.

Comment: What EF Provider are you using to talk to MySQL.  We will try to repro.

Comment: <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"></provider>

Comment: I developed a project where I used BreezeJs, in development phase I used MS SQLServer and everything ok. Then I moved to MySql using this guide "http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?174,601264,601264" to connect same project with a  MySql Database. Then I got this issue. Thanks for your help!!!